# What are the mathematical properties of natural exponential function that lead to its usefulness in artificial intelligence?

Tags: math

In mathematics, there is a proof that the following infinite series converges to a constant irrational number, denoted by $e$, called as Euler's number or Euler's constant or Napier's constant. The value of $e$ lies between 2 and 3.

$$1 + \dfrac{1}{1!} +  \dfrac{1}{2!} +  \dfrac{1}{3!} + \cdots$$

The natural exponential function, defined as follows, has some interesting properties

$$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$$
$$f(x) = e^x$$

It is used in several algorithms and in the definitions of functions like [SoftMax](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/22426/which-paper-introduced-the-term-softmax).
I am interested in knowing the possible mathematical characteristics that lead this function useful in artificial intelligence.

The following are the properties I am aware of. But, I am not sure about how some of them will be useful

1. **Non-linearlity**: Activation functions are intended to provide non-linearity. So, it is a candidate for activation functions due to this property. You can check its graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1cxgy5ry6k).
2. **Differentiability**:  Loss functions used for in back-propagation algorithm [need to be differentiable](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/28884/18758). So, it can be a candidate for usage in loss functions too.

$$\dfrac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R}$$

3. **Continuity**: I am not sure how this property is useful in algorithms. Intuitively, you can check from graph provided above that it is continuous.
4. **Smoothness**: I am not sure how this property is useful in algorithms. But [seems useful](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/29896/18758). The natural exponential function [has the smoothness property](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/28588/18758).

$$\dfrac{d^n}{d^nx} e^x = e^x \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } n \in \mathbb{N}$$.

Are there any other properties like non-linearily, differentiability, smoothness etc., for the natural exponential function that make it superior to use in AI algorithms?

Comment: I think this question is a bit broad because a function may be used in different ways, in different contexts, and for different purposes. I think you're interested in ML (and maybe specifically in neural networks) and not the whole AI. If that's the case, I would start by replacing "AI" with "ML" or be more specific, then I would try to motivate a little more why you're asking this question. For example, in logic-based AI, maybe the characteristics that you mention are not even useful. Where would a function be used in those contexts? These are all issues that I see with this post.

Comment: @nbro But I am not sure there are many branches in AI that use $e^x$. And it is true that there are plenty of branches, but, if we view from the perspective of function only, there are finite properties for $e^x$. Am I wrong anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

The question must be split in two:

Use in softmax: softmax is based in the concept of cross entropy, logistic regression, logistic function ... . All these concepts includes exponential or logarithmic in its formulation.

Use in activation functions:

- monotonic: a non-monotonic function will give same output to different inputs, disturbing the concept of distance/error.
- non-linear: a linear activation function collapses the layer with the next one, thus, it is useless.
- differentiable: necessary to use back-propagation.

Answer (score 1):

While all the properties you list are true, the essential parts are the **Differentiability** and the fact that you build a **nice probability distribution from it**.

The unnormalized scores the neural network puts out *before* we apply softmax to them may very well contain negative values. Applying the exponential function is a great way to build a probability distribution from a given vector, disregarding the sign of the values.